# Why did Visual Studio break after .NET Framework package installation?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I've seen similar questions posted before but none of the solutions solved my issue.

Basically: I had a new windows form up and running, the build ran just fine.

I started a new project a few days later, that required .NET to be installed. So naturally, I installed the package. After that, none of my projects would build. Now, none of my projects will render.

I get error codes and failure to build.

[image: build error]

[image: error 2]

[image: will not build .exe]

I have made changes to the project's properties, however, this sis nothing. In fact, it created a few more LNK errors. I'm assuming this will be a path issue, I have done the code enough to know the dangers of my second-guessing.

If you need me to provide more detail, please ask.

Comment: I suggest you create a simple program to test whether it is a problem after installing .net. If not, I would appreciate if you could provide detailed error information, including lnk errors.

Comment: I followed your suggestion starting a new project. Then i tried a couple more, seems the code error is was generating code LNK2001. this is apparently a common error involving Visual studio. However, sudden.  It may have to with a recent file transfer, but i update the path. Currently, all my projects are a mess and scattered all over my file system. So to be clear: I gathered that the system is not building the exe for some programs and the .dll file for another. This happened before and after a file transfer and properties path update in linker.

Comment: If your project is used to build dll, I suggest that you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [How to: Debug from a DLL project in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2019). If it is difficult to solve [lnk2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=vs-2019), I would appreciate it if you could provide the detailed information, and I am very happy to help you.